# Cloud Functions: Access System Fonts

Tags: firebase, truetype, google-cloud-functions, hummus.js

Im am using hummusJS to manipulate PDF Files with Firebase Cloud functions.

As far as I know, Hummus requires to have access to an actual true type font file, to be able to use fonts in PDFs.
In my local env I'm using this:

[https://github.com/devongovett/font-manager](http://font-manager)

It has some depends on some libfontconfig-dev, its not working on cloud functions.

According to this post there is no way to use hummus without fonts:

https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/issues/120

I could store the needed fonts online and download it everytime into the function, but this doesn't feel right.

Any Idea how I could make this work?

edit: I'm not picky, I would use every font beside Comic Sans

Comment: Have you tried packaging the fonts in your functions directory, which will get uploaded when you deploy?

Comment: I tried that, but it seems I miss fundamentals in packaging. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the TrueType File into my package.

Just added the local file as dependency to package.json, its
working on Firebase Functions.

Comment: hey jbb! how did you do that? adding a ttf as dependency in package.json doesnt work for me :(

Comment: as far a I remember I did create a npm package like this: 
{
  "name": "myfonts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Arial font file",
  "main": "arial.ttf",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

I did put this under dependencies later. But I don't think this is correct and I ended up not using it.
Do you use firebase functions? **I think if you just have the ttf in your functions folder it will get deployed with your functions and you can use it via file system inside your function.**

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! :) yes, i'm trying to use it in firebase functions and reference the font from node-canvas to draw on the canvas with a specific font. so i think it has to be set as a system font somehow, because only v1 of node-canvas is available on firebase functions and v1 only supports the use of installed system fonts. direct loading of fonts files was introduced in v2 :( already tried the npm packages for the specific font ("npm-font-open-sans") but this didn't help. the ttf file itself is already included in my node package.

Comment: have you could tried this: [link](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/fonts-in-node-canvas-bbf0b6b0cabf) ?
maybe it works on firebase functions aswell

Comment: thanks for your effort! i finally found a working solution. works on firebase functions and google cloud functions. i just use the following precompiled version of node-canvas: "canvas-prebuilt": "2.0.0-alpha.2" in my package.xml. alpha.3/4/5 have broken font support, but alpha.2 works fine :)

Comment: I can confirm that just putting the font in your functions folder in Firebase works.