# How to install custom fonts in Google cloud function for imagemagick

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick, pango

I am working with ImageMagic with firebase cloud function. I am using non english language so for that I am using Pango. With Pango custom fonts is not working

```
convert -size 200x200 -font pathToMyFonts pango:sometext pango_test.png
```

In the above command instead of pango: if I use caption: then custom font is working correctly. but for non english character it's creating problem

In documentation I found that Pango will work with only installed fonts so I have try many [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43937028/4803607) to install the pango on cloud function env. But nothing is working.

Any Idea how I could make this work?

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Comment: No. I didn't found answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Havnt tried it with firebase cloud function, but locally it worked when I installed the fonts, and for "-font" I put the name of the newly installed font without the extension, ie ae_Khalid instead of ae_Khalid.ttf